# Queued Spinlock

Tags: c++, synchronization, linux-kernel, mutex, spinlock

I happened to stumble upon Queued Spinlock and would like to implement in C++. I googled a bit for info on this but wasn't able to get proper documentation.

Any documentation / implementation tips would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

I have the following doubt in the code pointed by Michael Brown

```
// represents processor in wait queue of the spinlock
struct qsl_entry
{

// next processor in the queue that is waiting to enter section
qsl_entry* next;

// indicates whether the access to section has been granted to processor
int state;

};

// queued spinlock
struct qsl
{

// the first processor in the queue that is waiting to enter section
qsl_entry* head;

};

// requests access to critical section guarded by the spinlock,
// if the section is already taken it puts processor to wait
// and insert it into queue
// lck - queued lock that used to guard section
// ent - entry that represent processor in queue of the spinlock
void lock_qsl(qsl* lck, qsl_entry* ent)
{
__asm
{
    mov eax, ent;
    mov ebx, lck;

    // prepare queue entry
    mov [eax], 0;
    mov edx, eax;
    mov [eax]qsl_entry.state, 1;

    // store it as the last entry of the queue -- Is this what is line is doing ?
    // ebx contains address of lck & [ ebx ] refers to address pointed by lck & 
    // it is over written to ent. eax now contains the memory the lck was pointing to.
    lock xchg [ebx],eax;

    // if the section available grant access to processor?
    test eax, eax;
    jz enter_section;
        // link new entry with the rest of queue -- really ? are we nt overwritting
        // the next pointer here ?
        mov [eax],edx

        // wait for processor's turn
        wait1:
            pause;
            cmp [edx]qsl_entry.state, 1;
            je wait1;

    enter_section:
 }
}
```

Is this implementation even correct ? I doubt so !

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/100195/Queued-spinlocks seems a suitable implementation

Comment: Thanks for the link but I already found it in my google search. I should have added this in my question. The problem is it doesn't seem to have much documentation associated with it. For a complex topic such as this, some intuition would be great.

Comment: Ah yes, im sorry your question does state you wanted details. What details are you after?

The queued spinlock is a linked-list of spinning locks, one for each thread entering the critical section. The article states that this helps memory and cache issues when only one spin lock is used over multiple processors

Comment: Could you point to the algorithm/pseudocode ? Or some reference ?

Comment: Conceptually, this is similar to a Semaphore. Except the counter is split into boolean's, and placed inside the linked list (fifo). If you want more theory that might help. Otherwise the implementation linked above is your best bet

Comment: Appreciate it. If you don't mind a full fledged explanation with examples would be very very helpful.

Comment: Heya. I feel details of this are better placed on wikipedia. So will attempt an entry and post back here. p.s. the code is correct.

Comment: wait1:
            pause;
            cmp [edx]qsl_entry.state, 1;
            je wait1;
In this piece of code, we are comparing value of gsl_entry.state to 1. Shouldn't this be protected by a lock ? We have another process writing to it & we could have partial reads.

Comment: As long as the data is aligned on a double word boundary (and the compiler will do that), then the `cmp` operation is atomic.

Answer (score 3):

Author of the code in question here. First let me state the code **is correct**. I just wrote more detailed explanation of the code here: http://kataklinger.com/index.php/queued-spinlocks/

Also I have another implementation, which is somewhat simpler, but not as good as this one (correct nevertheless). <s>I will see if I can find it somewhere.</s> I found it. Here's the link to discussion that includes both implementations: http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=15389

The last post also has link that discuss queued spinlocks in more depths: http://www.cs.rice.edu/~johnmc/papers/tocs91.pdf

Yeah, I'm bit late for the party, but I was this post just few days ago and it inspired me to write better explanation of the code.